# Firebase email or Facebook authentication with BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry, qml, firebase, blackberry-cascades

I want to use Firebase with a BlackBerry 10 Native + Cascades App.

The problem is Firebase has no libraries for BlackBerry 10. I have done some research saying that I can use the REST API, but I cannot find anywhere on how to do email or facebook login via pure REST. Everything involves downloading the Javascript API which I cannot do as QML support with JS is giving me issues.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, you can't do authentication via REST. It requires that a user log into a third party service and enter credentials (not possible without a UI). You could create your own UI for authentication and generate your own [custom tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-custom).

Once you have a token, you can pass that to the REST API by adding ?auth= to the URL.